# Publicando sistema com Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Existe instalador executável do `Entity Framework 6` para servidores.

Publiquei o sistema num servidor Windows server 2008, e não esta funcionando.
Esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   Context.ControleHorasContext.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity
>   Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the
>   'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

Já verifiquei os dados de conexão no WebConfig, e esta tudo correto.

```
<add name="Entities"     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.csdl|res://*/Con text.ControleHorasContext.ssdl|res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.msl;provider =System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data  source=VMCPT100;initial catalog=ControleHoras;persist security info=True;user  id=*;password=*;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramewo rk&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Também verifiquei a pasta bin, e me certifiquei de que o arquivo EntityFramework.dll esta lá.

Comment: Procurando pelo erro na internet tem muita coisa. Vê se algo [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754317/entity-framework-4-1-on-web-server) pode te ajudar

Comment: @Otavio, isso não está relacionado com o Servidor. O Problema está na sua aplicação. Poderia fornecer mais detalhes de como está sua classe `DBContext` ?

Comment: Verifica a sua classe de ControleHorasContext se nao existe algum erro de decoração, poste o codigo da classe para mais detalhes.

Comment: @RenanCarlos, Não sei qual a relação também com mvc ...

Comment: @OtavioCamargo `user id=controleHoras;password=cpt123`, cuidado com o que posta aqui.

Comment: Verifique se a .dll do SqlClient está referenciada no projeto.

Comment: De uma olhada nessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168852/61561 , talvez isso resolva o problema com o provider

Answer (score -1):

Eu já consegui resolver esta questão corrigindo a instalação do entity framework.

Minha solução possui dois projetos: um para o site MVC, e outro para acesso a dados.

O problema estava ocorrendo porque eu instalei o entity framewokr pelo nuget apenas para o projeto de acesso a dados, onde efetivamente é utilizado.

Isso funciona perfeitamente no ambiente local.

Mas quando gerava o pacote para publicação, reclamava que o entity framework não estava instalado corretamente.

A solução foi instalar o entity framework na solution (todos os projetos).